# Cesar decryption. How to deal with non-alphanumerical chars | JS

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, encryption

Build a function which takes an encrypted string as argument. it's a Cesar encryption. Like: encrypted character + 5 (or whatever number).

**Problem: The encrypted string contains non-alphanumeric chars like " " or "!".**

I build a very verbose function which is attached below for completion. **The main part to solve the above mentioned problem is:**

```
  let z = /[^A-^Z]/g;
  if (strIn.search(z) !== 0) {
    let n = strIn.search(z);
    wordArr.splice(n, 0, strIn[n]);
```

`strIn`  is the uppercase version of the input string (the encrypted string)
`wordArr` is the decrypted version **without** non alphanumeric chars.

I tried to loop like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < strIn.length; i++) {
    if (strIn.search(z) !== 0) {
      let n = strIn.search(z);
      wordArr.splice(n, 0, strIn[n]);
    }
  }
```

I also tried a while loop. Similar successless. 
I also tried to map. But than console throws:

```
 strIn.map is not a function
```

**Could anyone explain this behavior and give me just a hint how to solve this problem.
1.) Using a loop 
2.) Using something better if possible**

Here my verbose code for reference or whatever:

```
function rot13(str) {
  let upper = str.toUpperCase().split("");
  let index = [];
  let decode = [];

  const alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (var i = 0; i < upper.length; i++) {
    if (alpha.indexOf(upper[i]) === -1) {
      index.push(upper[i]);
    } else if (alpha.indexOf(upper[i]) !== -1) {
      index.push(alpha.indexOf(upper[i]));
    }
  }
  console.log("index: " + index);

  let elem = index.map(function(a, b) {
    if (a === 13) {
      return a - 13;
    } else if (a + 13 <= 26) {
      return a + 13;
    } else if (a + 13 > 26) {
      return a - 13;
    }
  });

  console.log("elem :" + elem);

  for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
    decode.push(alpha[elem[j]]);
  }
  let word = decode.join("");
  let strIn = upper.join("");

  console.log("strIn: " + strIn);

  let z = /[^A-^Z]/g;
  // let z = /[\!]/g;

  let wordArr = Array.from(word);

    if (strIn.search(z) !== 0) {
      let n = strIn.search(z);
      wordArr.splice(n, 0, strIn[n]);
    }

  console.log("wordArr: " + wordArr);
  console.log(wordArr.join(""));

  console.log(strIn.search(z));
}

rot13("SERR CVMMN!");
```

Comment: `rot13` is just a special case of a Caesar shift (so I don't see why you are hard-wiring in the case of 13), and if you are going outside of the 26 letters in the alphabet, "Caesar shift" is at best under-specified. What is one supposed to *do* with characters like `'!'`? Leave them alone? Shift them to other nonalphabetical characters? Your question is thus unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: If your goal is removing those characters, try `strIn.replace(/[^A-^Z]/g, '')`

Comment: Sorry, my question is unclear. If you pass for example "SERR CVMMN!" in the function. Like rot13(SERR CVMMN!). The function will output "Free Pizza!". I have figured out how to shift the alphanumeric chars – in this case 13 steps. And to push them into a new array,. But I don't know, how I have to deal with non-alphanumeric chars. Like the empty space or the "!".

Comment: You can only encrypt / decrypt characters in your alphabet (`alpha` in your code). What you do with the rest is up to you. Generally they are retained for ROT13 applications and the (upper / lower) case is kept as well. Removing them is just another option that you can take. You can always expand your alphabet (and you will find out that hardcoding 26 was probably not a good idea when you do that). Of course, you want to use an alphabet with an even number and replace the value 13 as well with alphabetSize / 2  when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem. Somewhat.

When I passed an encrypted message into a function like `rot13("LBH QVQ VG!");` I get the wished result "You did it!". The non-alphanumericals are **displayed at the correct position and where not shifted and the alpahnumericals are shifted correctly.**

I simply added " ", "!" and "?", "." to my `const alpha`. If the indexed char of the input string was "`>=26`" (end of alphabet)the function is not allowed to shift these chars and to leave them on the position. It is this part

```
  if (a >= 26) {
      return a;
    }
```

In my "shift character method"

```
  let elem = index.map(function(a, b) {
    if (a >= 26) {
      return a;
    } else if (a === 13) {
      return a - 13;
    } else if (a + 13 <= 26) {
      return a + 13;
    } else if (a + 13 > 26) {
      return a - 13;
    }
  });
```

`elem` should get the correct indices to match with my `const alpha`.

alpha:

```
 const alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !?.";
```

Before it was `const alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

With the indices from `elem` I got the correct values (chars) from `alpha` due to a for loop… I push them into an array called `decode`.

```
  for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
    decode.push(alpha[elem[j]]);
  }
```

`word` is the searched term which is logged out.

```
let word = decode.join("");
```

I would appreciate it, if someone could show me a far more elegant way to solve this challenge.

```
function rot13(str) {
  let upper = str.toUpperCase().split("");
  let index = [];
  let decode = [];

  const alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !?.";

  for (var i = 0; i < upper.length; i++) {
    if (alpha.indexOf(upper[i]) !== -1) {
      index.push(alpha.indexOf(upper[i]));
    } else if (alpha.indexOf(upper[i]) > 26) {
      index.push(alpha.indexOf(upper[i]));
    }
  }

  let elem = index.map(function(a, b) {
    if (a >= 26) {
      return a;
    } else if (a === 13) {
      return a - 13;
    } else if (a + 13 <= 26) {
      return a + 13;
    } else if (a + 13 > 26) {
      return a - 13;
    }
  });

  for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
    decode.push(alpha[elem[j]]);
  }
  let word = decode.join("");

  console.log(word);
}

rot13("LBH QVQ VG!"); // You did it!
```